# DocuSign Apex Toolkit: Dynamic Add Recipient (Receives a Copy)

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, docusignapextoolkit

I am using [How to use embedded signing](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/salesforce/how-to/embedded-sending-signing/) guide.

I would like to extend the code to add a new Recipient that will only receives a copy after the signing is completed.

I successfully updated the DocuSign Envelope Template to add Recipient (User record, Role: CC, Action: Receives a Copy).

I want to cc a specific email address based on the Case data.

I tried using this code:

```
new List<dfsle.Recipient> {
    dfsle.Recipient.newEmbeddedSigner(),
    dfsle.Recipient.fromSource(
        'John Smith', // Recipient name
        'john@smith.com', // Recipient email
        null, //Optional phone number
        'CC', //Role Name. Specify the exact role name from template
        null)
            .withRole(dfsle.Recipient.TYPE_CARBON_COPY)
};
```

John Smith was added as `Needs to Sign`.

Is it possible to use Apex Toolkit to programmatically add a Recipient as Receives a Copy?  Or do I need to create multiple DocuSign Envelope Templates with different Recipients for Receives a Copy?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, used wrong API.  Should be using **withType**

```
new List<dfsle.Recipient> {
    dfsle.Recipient.newEmbeddedSigner(),
    dfsle.Recipient.fromSource(
        'John Smith', // Recipient name
        'john@smith.com', // Recipient email
        null, //Optional phone number
        'CC', //Role Name. Specify the exact role name from template
        null)
            .withType(dfsle.Recipient.TYPE_CARBON_COPY)
};
```